# How to float 3 divs side by side irrespective of length?

Tags: css, css-position, html

So I want to float three divs side by side. Right now I have them with `display: inline-block;` and floating left, but when the window gets too small, the rightmost `<div>` is forced to be below the other two.

Also I need it so that the rightmost and leftmost `<div>` have a certain maximum width, and the center `<div>` should change it's width to fill the window. (I'm giving you this information in case any solutions interfere with this). How do I achieve what I want?

### Edit

The container for this `<div>` (whether it be the body, or another `<div>`), has to be of width 100%. I need three side by side `<div>`s positioned like this:

[image: Needed layout]

This should keep it's form as I make the window smaller or larger. This is the HTML/CSS I have now:

```
<div class="app-view">
  <div class="search-form"/>
  <div class="results-view"/>
  <div class="quick-viz"/>
</div>

.app-view-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
}

.search-form {
  border-right: solid 1px #d1d2d4;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  min-height: 900px;
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  background: #78787b;
}

.results-view {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 10px;
  float: left;
  min-height: 900px;
  min-width: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 55%;
}

.quick-viz {
  display: inline-block !important;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  background: #78787b;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: a fiddle would be great!

Comment: why a max width to those divs? (without max width just use `width:33%;` or the like)

Comment: What are you working with so far? May I also suggest editing your 'question' to make it more applicable to the entire SO audience-- not just you.

Comment: _"How do I achieve what I want?"_ What have you tried?

Comment: er.. I told you what I tried - I'm working on a JS fiddle right now

Comment: OK, for some reason I can't get a fiddle to work - but I've posted my code now

Answer (score 4):

Updated answer, exactly follows this structure (as requested):

[image]

Use a container:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="b"></div>
    <div class="c"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.a, .b, .c {
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    width: 21%;
    margin: 2%
}
.b {
    width: 46%;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/dQQhz/4/

Comment: Updated after new details from OP